# Printing with a Niimbot Bluetooth printer in Android

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth

I have a Niimbot portable Bluetooth printer that I want to use on my custom Android app to print barcodes. There could be others exactly the same as the Niimbot D11 mode like this (it's a Chinese product)

[https://www.amazon.com/UPANV-Printer-Wireless-Portable-Bluetooth/dp/B089M76Y8L/ref=sr_1_2?dchild=1&keywords=niimbot&qid=1601303365&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089M76Y8L)

This is the app that lets you use the printer

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gengcon.android.jccloudprinter&hl=en

There is this library that I tested https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth which lets you connect to a Bluetooth printer and send text or image. So far I'm able to connect with the printer but any print order just makes it "beep", nothing comes out printed.

Looking for alternatives to accomplish the printing.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to solve this

Comment: @BaluSangem I was. Send me your contact or somewhere we can follow up on this conversation. I'll be pleased to help :).

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/sbkcse

Comment: https://discord.gg/4VcBPkRK

Comment: Hello, @monchoz, would you be willing to write up an answer, or have you already published it somewhere else?

Comment: Hi @MichaelArtman, apologies for the late response, I was able to solved it indeed, there is an official SDK that allows you to interact with the hardware, I can gladly share details with you (in case you need it) :)

Comment: Hello, @monchoz I am very interested in seeing what you have come up with!

Comment: Hey @MichaelArtman, send me a your contact or somewhere we can continue the conversation to share my findings :)

Comment: @RamonZuniga can you share so other can use it. I am trying to send data via the web ble, i can connect but nothing i send to it gets printer. My guess is that i am not sending the data correctly or the correct data.

Comment: Hi @user1170117 You can download everything you need from this link, including PDF documentation and a library file to work with the printer (D11 only): https://www.buymeacoffee.com/monchoz/e/108303

Comment: Hi @RamonZuniga i am looking at implementing similar functionality for an iOS app, do you know if there was any references to an iOS SDK that I can use? I did download your library for android to try and make sense of it but iOS's Bluetooth framework is too different