# Niimbot printer and Android Studio

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth

I have a Niimbot Bluetooth printer that I want to use on my custom Android app to print labels. I've used this library https://github.com/mazenrashed/Printooth. I'm able to connect with the printer but every command makes it beeping. But nothing comes out.

Did anyone manage to print something out?

See also: [Printing with a Niimbot Bluetooth printer in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104313/printing-with-a-niimbot-bluetooth-printer-in-android)

Thanks...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.